# JavaScript Regex - match without the trailing slash

Tags: javascript, regex

Given the following regular expression:

```
\/page1\/id\/(.*)\/type\/(.*)\/$
```

Which is to match the following URL path (and works):

```
/page1/id/331/type/test23/
```

How can I modify the regex to still match with the last slash missing, i.e:

```
/page1/id/331/type/test23
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just throw a question mark before the final slash to make it optional.

```
\/page1\/id\/\d+\/type\/[^\/]+\/?$
```

Also, you may want to make that ID non-greedy, or match numbers specifically (updated regex for you).

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. The problem I have with added a ? after the slash, it then matches anything after it (.e.g /page1/id/331/type/test23/3234/234/234/234/).

Comment: No. That's not the `?`s fault. It's your greedy `.*`s in the middle, which I've removed for you. "Greedy" meaning it will consume as much as it can.

Comment: Absolutely brilliant! Thank you.

Comment: Isn't `\d+` equally greedy? Obviously, you solve that by restricting to digits, but I don't see what that has to do with greediness?

Comment: One more question, how would I ignore any ?key=value strings at the end? (Would it be best to just strip them out before matching?)

Comment: @BramVanroy `\d+` is greedy, yes. It will consume as many *digits* as it can, which is what you want here. It will stop at the next non-digit, which ought to be a `/`. It's better/easier to remove the query params before matching. If you're doing this in client-side JS, match against `window.location.pathname`.

Comment: No, what I meant was: how is his `.*` 'more greedy' than your `\d+`.

Comment: @BramVanroy They're both considered greedy unless you add a ? afterwords, i.e. `*?` or `+?`.  `.` simply matches more characters than `\d` which means that `.*` will try matching the following `/` and everything thereafter, whereas `\d` won't simply because a `/` is not a digit.